# How to query firebase firestore usage by source (admin vs web)

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-admin-sdk

is there any way in firebase or google cloud console to view the firestore document reads by source (admin or web sdk)? we had a massive spike and need this info to triage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All options are listed on the documentation page on [monitoring usage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/monitor-usage), but there is no view of what specific document caused the spike in reads. If you want such a thing, you'll have to build it yourself - which unfortunately won't help for this incident that has already occurred.